# Change of position of object with and without glasses/spectacles

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, vision, glass

If I look at an object with my glasses on and then remove my glasses, the object and everything in my field of vision seem to undergo a displacement. From my judgment, the displacement is greater for objects on the periphery of my glasses and reduces towards the centre.

1. Is this actually happening or am I being fooled by an optical illusion?
2. If this does happen, why don't I walk/drive into things? Can catch a ball etc?

If this is a real effect, I assume as the effect is reduced towards the centre of the glasses, and within your field of vision, you always centre the object you are focusing on, then the overall effect is minimal. And hand-eye/car-object coordination would also play a part.

Answer (score 1):

Without spectacles, the light entering your eyes is coming directly from the the objects. When you put on spectacles, the light entering your eyes is coming from from an image created by the lenses. The positions of those images (the main object of interest and everything surrounding it) is going to be slightly (or strongly) different, because the paths of the light coming from those images are modified so that the optics of your eyeballs can produce sharp images on your retinas.

So, yes, the change in apparent position of the objects, based on where the images form on your retinas, is real. Did the original object move? No. But your eyes and brain work together to tell you where things are located, and that's based on where the retinal images form.

Your brain, eyes, and muscle control all work together to learn how to move around without falling or bumping into things.

By the way, the images on the retina are upside down compared to the images/objects that are outside your body. Your brain has learned, from the time of your being a baby, how to interpret that, and control your muscles accordingly.

Edit to mention lense edge effects: Light coming through the edges of spectacles will be distorted because of spherical abberation. Most lenses in spectacles are based on spherical surfaces (with a cylindrical modification for astigmatism), but the edges of a spherical surface don't focus images at the same location as the central eyesight line of the lense.

Comment: This effect is enhanced if you are looking down on a water surface from above (or through a face mask from below).  The bending of beams by refraction causes things to appear closer, and if you are looking at an angle to the surface, they can appear displaced in position. (Try hitting a fish with a gig.)